# Using jQuery and cloning children with embedded labels and altering the label content

Tags: jquery, clone

Using jQuery I have UL with an LI and within it is a div that displays based on slideToggle.  The div inside the LI has an array of children div objects and each of these has some labels and inputs. I need to add more children and edit the content of the new children.  This will ultimately be integrated with a handlebars template.

The attached sample code does all that is required and I stripped it down for the sake of simplicity, but I believe there must be a more efficient way to do this.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Session Template</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
                $(this).on('click', '.addApp', function (e) {
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings('.notesDiv').slideToggle(500);
                });
                $(this).on('click', '.addBtn', function (e) {
                //    var newval = ($('.setNum').length + 1);
                //    var newInputID = 'snumber' + newval;
                //    $('.beforeme').prepend('<div class="data"<input class=setNum id="' + newInputID + '"/></div>');
                //    alert($(this).parent().children().length - 2);
                    var div = $(this).closest('.cntTest').find(".data")[0];
                    console.log(div)
                    $(this).parent().children('.data:last').clone().insertBefore($(this).parent().children('.beforeme'));
                    $(this).parent().children('.data:last').children('label').html($(this).parent().children().length - 2);
                });
            });
    </script>
    <style>
        .titleText{float:left;font-weight:bold;margin-left:10px;}
        .titleBtnAdd{float:right;margin-right:5px;}
        .data{width:25px;border:1px solid black;text-align:center;height:20px;}
        .setNum{width:21px;text-align:center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body style="width:400px;">
    <div id="sessContainer" style="border:1px solid red;padding:2px;">
        <div class="titleDiv" style="border:1px solid blue;display:block; height:50px;">
            <p><span class="titleText">this is some title text</span><span class="titleBtnAdd"><img class="addApp" src="info-red.gif" /></span></p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="notesDiv" style="background-color:cornsilk;border:1px solid green; display:none; height:100px;margin:2px;">
            <span class="notesText">This is the representation of notes that will be displayed in the notes div and will show
                and hide based on the titleBtnAdd click on the siblings div.  TSo is the green border.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="cntTest">
        <div class="addBtn" style="background-color:wheat">Event1: Add participants</div>
        <div class="data"><label class="setNum">1</label></div>
        <div class="data"><label class="setNum">2</label></div>
        <div class="data"><label class="setNum">3</label></div>
        <div class="beforeme">this is a description of Event1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cntTest">
        <div class="addBtn" style="background-color:wheat">Event2: Add participants</div>
        <div class="data"><label class="setNum">1</label></div>
        <div class="data"><label class="setNum">2</label></div>
        <div class="data"><label class="setNum">3</label></div>
        <div class="data"><label class="setNum">4</label></div>
        <div class="beforeme">this is a description of Event2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A reduced code can be:

```
var div = $(this).closest('.cntTest').find(".data:last");
div.clone().find("label").text((i,txt) => +txt + 1).closest('.data').insertAfter(div);
```

Steps:

- get last data div
- clone
- change label [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)
- get parent
- insert after

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addApp', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.titleDiv').siblings('.notesDiv').slideToggle(500);
});
$(document).on('click', '.addBtn', function (e) {
    var div = $(this).closest('.cntTest').find(".data:last");
    div.clone().find("label").text((i, txt) => +txt + 1).
                   closest('.data').insertAfter(div);
});
```

```css
.titleText {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.titleBtnAdd {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.data {
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
}
.setNum {
  width: 21px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


<div id="sessContainer" style="border:1px solid red;padding:2px;">
    <div class="titleDiv" style="border:1px solid blue;display:block; height:50px;">
        <p><span class="titleText">this is some title text</span><span class="titleBtnAdd"><img class="addApp"
                                                                                                src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/e9f4f5/d90909"/></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="notesDiv"
         style="background-color:cornsilk;border:1px solid green; display:none; height:100px;margin:2px;">
            <span class="notesText">This is the representation of notes that will be displayed in the notes div and will show
                and hide based on the titleBtnAdd click on the siblings div.  TSo is the green border.</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>

<div class="cntTest">
    <div class="addBtn" style="background-color:wheat">Event1: Add participants</div>
    <div class="data"><label class="setNum">1</label></div>
    <div class="data"><label class="setNum">2</label></div>
    <div class="data"><label class="setNum">3</label></div>
    <div class="beforeme">this is a description of Event1</div>
</div>
<div class="cntTest">
    <div class="addBtn" style="background-color:wheat">Event2: Add participants</div>
    <div class="data"><label class="setNum">1</label></div>
    <div class="data"><label class="setNum">2</label></div>
    <div class="data"><label class="setNum">3</label></div>
    <div class="data"><label class="setNum">4</label></div>
    <div class="beforeme">this is a description of Event2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: gaetanoM, thanks for providing the streamline.  Your integration of the loop was helpful as well.